# docker-compose health check passed, still unhealthy

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, docker-compose, health-check

> *`condition` was removed compose spec in versions 3.0 to 3.8 but is now back!  Using version of the compose spec v3.9, you can use `condition` as an option in [long syntax form of `depends_on`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#long-syntax-1).*

I use docker compose to start MySQL and Java Web projects,
The startup of JavaWeb needs to rely on MySQL to create complete data, so I use [healthcheck](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#long-syntax-1)

But there is a problem with the  `healthcheck` of mysql, this is my `docker-compose`

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"  

services:

  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./mysql
    command: [
        'mysqld',
        '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
        '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        '--default-time-zone=+8:00',
        '--lower-case-table-names=1'
    ]
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: fuba-db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: fb123456
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysql -uroot -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD  -e 'SELECT * FROM factor_header' fuba-db "
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3

  redis:
    build:
      ......

  nginx:
    build:
      ......

  fubaquant:
    build:
      context: ./webapps
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/java/jar:/home/ruoyi  #jar包
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
```

The statement in error is:

```
test: "mysql -uroot -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD  -e 'SELECT * FROM factor_header' fuba-db "
```

The console outputs :

```
pro-mysql-1      | 2022-04-07T08:16:54.203710Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
container for service "mysql" is unhealthy
```

*Since fubaquant depends_on mysql healthcheck, fubaquant is not started either*

The health check log of the mysql container is:

[image: docker-compose up]

I checked th healthcheck log of mysql and it's also healthy

[image: mysql log]

thanks for any help

Comment: @Luuk I've tried many answer, but none of them work for me

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please read the complete line in your first picture just before the `container for service "mysql" is unhealthy`  (and try to solve this warning)

Comment: To solve this you need to find `--initialize-insecure` on this page (or read the complete page): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured health check to only allow 3 retries, 1 second intervals. While compose is starting java, mysql service has not reached the healthy state within this 3s delay, so compose stops and report this error.
It's work after I increased the number of retries

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to run the health check with wrong user and password. You have

```yaml
healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "-u$mysql", "-p$123456",  "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
```

`$mysql` and `$123456` will try to be resolved the value of those variables. What you want is to use the following instead.

```yaml
healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "-u$MYSQL_USER", "-p$MYSQL_PASSWORD",  "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
```

This will then try to run `mysaqladmin` with the user `mysql` and password `123456` (both defined as env vars for the `mysql` service on the docker-compose)

Comment: I tried it and he still got the following error:

Comment: Which error exactly?

Comment: I re-edited docker-compose and has a new problem

Answer (score 1):

Configuring this in docker-compose.yml worked for me,

```
environment:
    MYSQL_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}
    MYSQL_ROOT_USER: ${MYSQL_ROOT_USER}
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
restart: on-failure
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysql -h ${MYSQL_HOST} -u  ${MYSQL_ROOT_USER} -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 20s
  retries: 10
```

I have set ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} value in .env folder.